# Laravel función count()

Tags: count

tengo una tabla tal que así:

| id | user_code | tipo | created_at | updated_at | ip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 186 | 9099 | Salida | 2022-03-22 08:14:50 | 2022-03-22 08:14:50 | 127.0.0.1 |
| 187 | 9100 | Salida | 2022-03-22 08:17:47 | 2022-03-22 08:17:47 | 127.0.0.1 |
| 188 | 9100 | Entrada | 2022-03-22 08:19:31 | 2022-03-22 08:19:31 | 127.0.0.1 |

Necesito hacer una suma de la última entrada de cada usuario, es decir, recorrer toda la tabla y coger el último registro de cada usuario para saber si está dentro o fuera.

Es decir, en este ejemplo, las entradas serían uno porque el último registro del 9099 es una salida y el del 9100 una entrada.

Con el siguiente código cuento todas las entradas que hay en la tabla pero no se me ocurre como decirle que solo quiero el último registro de cada uno de los usuarios (user_code) para saber si es una entrada o salida y ahí sumarlo, en realidad con las entradas me basta, lo otro lo resto del total de usuarios.

```
{{$active_users = DB::table('asistencias')->where('tipo','entrada')->count()}}
```

Any idea?

Comment: return DB::table('asistencias')->where('tipo','entrada')->latest(nombredelcampo')->first();

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo solventé viendo si el número de entradas por usuario era par o impar, par = salida e impar = entrada